# Why is the dropdown list displayed in one case and not the other?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In my view, the drop down list is displayed properly when I do this -

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedEstimateState, Model.EstimateStateList.ToSelectList(c => c.Value, c => c.Text), new { });
```

But not when I do this -

```
@{
    Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedEstimateState, Model.EstimateStateList.ToSelectList(c => c.Value, c => c.Text), new { });
}
```

What is the difference between the two?

Comment: Codeblocks doesnot render to your dropdownlist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is the `code block expression` , which is used to evaluate the expression. but it does not write out.  for more info check the razor syntax [Razor syntax](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/01/06/razor-syntax-quick-reference.aspx) and [`web-programming-using-the-razor-syntax`](http://www.asp.net/web-pages/tutorials/basics/2-introduction-to-asp-net-web-programming-using-the-razor-syntax)

```
@{
     Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedEstimateState, Model.EstimateStateList.ToSelectList(c => c.Value, c => c.Text), new { });

}
```

Where below  will write out the content (basically it's same as the response.write() with encoded )

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedEstimateState, Model.EstimateStateList.ToSelectList(c => c.Value, c => c.Text), new { });
```